# Typo3 v9 - Ajax Plugin JSON response is empty

Tags: json, ajax, plugins, typo3, response

Having the following TYPO3 Page for ajax request

```
ajaxAutocomplte_page = PAGE
ajaxAutocomplte_page {
    typeNum = 111871
    10 = COA_INT
    10 {
        userFunc = TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Core\Bootstrap->run
        extensionName= MyExt
        pluginName = AjaxAutocomplete
        vendorName = TYPO3
    }

    config {
        disableAllHeaderCode = 1
        additionalHeaders.10.header = Content-type:application/json
        xhtml_cleaning = 0
        debug = 0
        no_cache = 1
        admPanel = 0
    }
}
```

and returning the following response from Controller

```
 public function autocompleteJsonAction()
    {
        $query = $_GET['query'];

        $data = $this->templatesRepository->getAutocompleteData($query);

        $this->view->setVariablesToRender(['data']);
        $this->view->assign('data', $data);
    }
```

will produce JSON data on direct access of URL but not if I request async over javascript

What goes wrong in this case?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the below code maybe to help you. It's working for me.

```
<?php

public function autocompleteJsonAction() {
    $query = \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\GeneralUtility::_GET('query');
    $data = $this->templatesRepository->getAutocompleteData($query);

    $this->response->setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json', true);
    $this->response->sendHeaders();

    $theView = $this->objectManager->get("TYPO3\\CMS\\Extbase\\Mvc\\View\\JsonView");
    $theView->setControllerContext($this->controllerContext);
    $theView->assignMultiple([
        'items' => $data
    ]);
    $theView->setVariablesToRender(['items']);

    return $theView->render();
}
```

Hope this works for you too!

Comment: Thank you for your Feedback. Is there a better way the get the GET parameter from the request instead using `$_GET['query']`?

Comment: Looking for better way, is always cool! You can use TYPO3 Utility `GeneralUtility::_GET('query')`, `GeneralUtility::_POST('query')` or `GeneralUtility::_GP('query')`. For more, checkout [document here](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/7.6/en-us/ApiOverview/MainClasses/HighPriorityFunctions/Index.html#typo3-cms-core-utility-generalutility)